# How to loop between a list and dictionary to get frequencies in separate list (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to loop between a list full of characters to iterate and match up with the values in the dictionary to ultimately grab frequencies set on another list. For example:

```
a = ['NIEP','LOAS','IJFE','NIEP'] #list of characters
b = [] #empty list that would ultimately contain all the matching values
di = {'NIEP':0,'IJFE':0} #dictionary values with frequency counts set to 0
```

What b would ideally look like:

```
b = ['NIEP':2,'IJFE':1] #the numbers are the amount of times they repeat in list a
```

I have tried:

```
b = []
for x in di.keys():
    if x in a:
        b.append(di[x])
```

This returns an empty list and 0 values like [0,0]. I also tried:

```
b = [di[x] for x in a if x in di]
```

Which is the same thing but in a different format, it still returns the zeros just 3 of them.

Comment: This is a syntax error, which makes it hard to know precisely what you want: `b = ['NIEP':2,'IJFE':1] `

Answer (score 1):

Your `b` should be a dictionary because you're hunting the frequency of `a` matching reference with `di` dictionary. First iterate the list `a` then count if it exist in the dictionary `di`.

```
a = ['NIEP','LOAS','IJFE','NIEP'] #list of characters
di = {'NIEP':0,'IJFE':0} 

b = {}
for x in a:
    if x in di.keys():
        if x in b:
            b[x]+= 1
        else:
            b[x]=1
print(b)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'NIEP': 2, 'IJFE': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the builtin functionality [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
a = ['NIEP','LOAS','IJFE','NIEP']
di = {'NIEP':0,'IJFE':0} 
b = Counter(value for value in a if value in di)
print(b)
```

Output

```
Counter({'NIEP': 2, 'IJFE': 1})
```

But if you want a list of results

```
...
b = [{key: value} for key, value in b.items()]
print(b)
```

Output

```
[{'NIEP': 2}, {'IJFE': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are starting with a dictionary containing keys and zero values, it seems like you want to maintain these zero values for keys even if they are not in `a`. One way to do that is to take a count of the values in `a` if the key is in `di` and then merge them with the original `di`. For example:

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['NIEP','LOAS','IJFE','NIEP'] #list of characters
di = {'NIEP':0,'IJFE':0} 

b = {**di, **Counter(s for s in a if s in di)}
# {'NIEP': 2, 'IJFE': 1}
```

If `di` has additional keys, those will be preserved with the `0` value:

```
a = ['NIEP','LOAS','IJFE','NIEP'] #list of characters
di = {'NIEP':0,'IJFE':0, 'NULL': 0} 

b = {**di, **Counter(s for s in a if s in di)}
# {'NIEP': 2, 'IJFE': 1, 'NULL': 0}
```

A further alternative, if you want to keep the counter rather than a dict is to make the counter, then update it to get the zero values:

```
b = Counter(s for s in a if s in di)
b.update(di)

# b will be Counter({'NIEP': 2, 'IJFE': 1, 'NULL': 0})
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Counter from Collections -

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['NIEP','LOAS','IJFE','NIEP']

b  = dict(Counter(a))
print(b)
```

Result:

```
a = ['NIEP','LOAS','IJFE','NIEP']
```

Or, if you do not want to use a module then try -

```
b = {ele:a.count(ele) for ele in a} # A dict Comprehension

{'NIEP': 2, 'LOAS': 1, 'IJFE': 1}
```

Answer (score -2):

Or try:

```
>>> a = ['NIEP','LOAS','IJFE','NIEP']
>>> {k: a.count(k) for k in a}
{'NIEP': 2, 'LOAS': 1, 'IJFE': 1}
>>>
```

Comment: Ahh right, okay sure :)

Comment: So now you're all celebrating each other counting a word you're not supposed to count...